# Can you give me the right procedure to format, partition make usable the Hard Disk under the unix sistem. My unix is an IRIX 5.3

Tags: irix

I have INDIGO2 workstation On start up gives message unable to boot. how to solve the issue? if terminal is opened it is also not accepting any command.

Is it possible to upgrade Indigo 2 programs with old IRIX 5.3  to latest UBUNU distro?

Comment: You've probably got more [processing power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGI_Indigo%C2%B2_and_Challenge_M#Microprocessor) in a reasonably modern smartphone

Comment: There is a [BSD port](https://www.openbsd.org/sgi.html). I do have to say, your description lacks details (in the sense of "no details at all") and contradicts itself: How can you open a terminal window without booting?